# How to access an online txt file with AWK?

Tags: awk, remote-access

I would like to use an online database instead of a local file in AWK.
For instance:

```
awk 'END{print NR}' somelocalfile.txt
```

returns number of lines inside the file.

Now my question is, how can I calculate number of lines in an online txt file like [this one](http://www.pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt)? I prefer one-liner command.

I can `wget` and then apply `awk` command localy on it, but I think there can be more efficient approach.

Comment: should this question move to unix.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: You have two main choices: move the data to where the program is (copy the remote file to the local system) or move the program to where the data is (run your program on the remote system where the data is local). You might avoid a local permanent copy by piping the output from `wget` as standard input to your script, but that's about all that's going to make much difference (and that's fine if you only need it once, but wasteful if the file's large and you need it often). Other people may not be keen on letting you run your program on their machine — assume you need to make the data local.

Comment: Another question come in my mind, but I am going to ask it separately as it needs different answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526097/how-access-specific-part-of-data-with-awk

Comment: I've removed the awk tags as this has absolutely nothing to do with awk. You could replace awk with grep or any other tool and it's the same problem. You should add appropriate tags for whatever OS you are using and whatever tool you use to access URLs on that OS.

Comment: I am interested in a solution with AWK language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use wget:

```
wget -qO - http://path.com/tofile.txt | awk 'END{print NR}'
```

q means quiet, so you won't have any terminal outputs from wget. -O is the output which is set to stdout with the '-O -'.